# psql: query failing with powershell variable

Tags: powershell, psql

I am attempting to use PSQL in Powershell to set up users and associated passwords. I have all the user accounts set up, but I'm running into trouble doing the following:

```
$env:PGPASSWORD = "superUserPassword"
$USER_PASSWORD = "databaseUserPassword"

function set_password 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    (
        [string]$user,
        [string]$password
    )
    psql --% -h x.x.x.x -U admin@instance -d postgres -c "ALTER USER $user WITH PASSWORD '$password';"

}
set_password testUser $USER_PASSWORD
```

This code ends in an error that doesn't make a lot of sense:

```
psql : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$user"
At line:12 char:2
+     psql --% -h 10.77.227.166 -U dhadmin@dh-dataint-psql1 -d postgres ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR:  syntax ... near "'$user'":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
LINE 1: ALTER USER $user WITH PASSWORD '$password';
                   ^
```

If I use the actual username, rather than calling `$user`, it works just fine. I've tried using `'$user'`, similar to `password`, but that didn't work either, and generates the same error as above, just with `'$user'` instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're gonna have to remove `--%` if you want `$user` to expand before passing the argument to `psql`

Comment: Oh huh.. i had added the `--%` per the advice of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944212/no-password-supplied-positional-parameter-not-found-postgresql-powershell/31945033#31945033) to get the psql commands working in the first place. But you're right, after removing it, the command will run. I guess I hadn't been supplying arguments in that fashion in my previous testing, so the `--%` made sense.